# Merge two nested lists based on one attribute in Python

Tags: python, list

How do I merge two nested lists in Python based on one attribute?

For example

```
list1 = [[1,False,True],[2,True,True],[3,True,False]]
list2 = [[1,'Mr.','child'],[2,'Ms.','child'],[3,'Mr.','adult']]
```

I want to run something like:

```
merged_list = merge(list1,list2, where list1[0]==list2[0])
```

So final output would be:

```
merged_list = [[1,False,True,'Mr.','child'],[2,True,True,'Ms.','child'],[3,True,False,'Mr.','adult']]
```

I don't want to use nested for loop because of scalability; If I am trying to merge two lists with 1,000,000 rows it would take 1,000,000,000,000 iterations.

Comment: If you write the iterating yourself or use some language construct makes no difference on the iterations...

Comment: @vonbrand in Python it does. The big O complexity is the same, but the builtins and constructs can get you up to a 10 fold speed up.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about going through dict as a way to merge them?

```
def list_merge(list1, list2):
    d = {}
    for x in list1 + list2:
        d.setdefault(x[0], []).extend(x[1:])
    return [[x] + y for x, y in d.items()]
```

Comment: This gives a lot more output than the OP's expected output.

Comment: first pass I misread form of output, but it's in line with OP's parameters now, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

How about below code:

```
>>> list1 = [[1,False,True],[2,True,True],[3,True,False]]
>>> list2 = [[1,'Mr.','child'],[2,'Ms.','child'],[3,'Mr.','adult']]
>>> merge = [list([x[0]] + x[1:] + y[1:]) for x in list1 for y in list2 if x[0] == y[0]]
>>> merge
[[1, False, True, 'Mr.', 'child'], [2, True, True, 'Ms.', 'child'], [3, True, False, 'Mr.', 'adult']]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use enumerate to compare elements in two lists

```
list1 = [[1,False,True],[2,True,True],[3,True,False]]
list2 = [[1,'Mr.','child'],[2,'Ms.','child'],[3,'Mr.','adult']]

merged=[]
for i,j in enumerate(list1):
    if list2[i][0]==j[0]:
        merged.append(j+ list2[i][1:])
print merged
[[1, False, True, 'Mr.', 'child'], [2, True, True, 'Ms.', 'child'], [3, True, False, 'Mr.', 'adult']]
```

You can also use zip.

```
merged=[]
for  i, j in zip( list1,list2):
    if i[0] == j[0]:
        merged.append(i+j[1:])
```

The performance seems comparable using either loop:

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: merged=[]
   ...: for i,j in enumerate(list1):
   ...:     if list2[i][0]==j[0]:
   ...:         merged.append(j+ list2[i][1:])
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 µs per loop

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: merged=[]
   ...: for  i, j in zip( list1,list2):
   ...:     if i[0] == j[0]:
   ...:         merged.append(i+j[1:])
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 µs per loop
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you change the order of the elements of the lists...not sure if that's ok with the OP.

Comment: @Brionius The OP wants to compare the first element of each sublist which is what the code does.

Comment: Try changing `list1` to `[[2,True,True], [1,False,True], [3,True,False]]` and run your code again.

Comment: @Brionius The OP's example is comparing sublists at the same index, what has changing the order got to do with anything?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `defaultdict` to merge all the lists with the same first element, then convert that to the output structure that you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [[1,False,True],[2,True,True],[3,True,False]]
list2 = [[1,'Mr.','child'],[2,'Ms.','child'],[3,'Mr.','adult']]

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in list1 + list2:
    d[item[0]] += item[1:]

merged_list = [[k]+v for k, v in d.items()]

print merged_list

# OUTPUT:  [[1, False, True, 'Mr.', 'child'], [2, True, True, 'Ms.', 'child'], [3, True, False, 'Mr.', 'adult']]
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think this is a very neat and pythonic idea.

Comment: I think they're revenge downvotes - see the discussion above.  \*shrug\*

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [[1,False,True],[2,True,True],[3,True,False]]
list2 = [[1,'Mr.','child'],[2,'Ms.','child'],[3,'Mr.','adult']]
## if the order of the items doesn't matter , and you don't 
## need elements to be repeated you can do:
# res = [list(set(a+list2[i])) for i, a in enumerate(list1) if a[0] == list2[i][0]]
## otherwise you can do:
res = [list(a+list2[i][1:]) for i, a in enumerate(list1) if a[0] == list2[i][0]]
print res
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[1, False, True, 'Mr.', 'child'], [2, True, True, 'Ms.', 'child'], [3, True, False, 'Mr.', 'adult']]
```

Comment: does not match output expected

Comment: I went with sets first too but realised they would not work because of the repeated elements.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham which repeated elements ? it works fine, it just has the potential of messing up the ordering, and this can be taken care of too.

Comment: the OP wants to keep repeated elements in the output, I don't see how you could use sets to merge and keep the repeated elements.

Comment: This also does not work if the elements of the lists are in a different order.

Comment: @alfasin no worries. Brionius, I think you should go take a long walk and leave it for the OP to decide if order matters.

Comment: @Brionius if you want to post a different question with new requirements that you invented - be my guest :)

Comment: The OP asks "How do I merge two nested lists in Python based on one attribute?", not "How do I merge two nested lists in Python based on the order of the lists?"  Your code merges based on the order, not an "attribute" of the lists.

Comment: @Brionius, bottom line is that you did not ask the question, you are not the OP and it is not up to you to interpret on behalf of the OP what he/she means. If either of our answers do not meet the requirements the OP will undoubtedly inform us, as it stands our output matches the OP's requirements so as previously suggested, keep walking.